# Почему при парсинге выходит только часть текста?

Tags: python

Я пишу свой первый парсер на Python. Eще новичок в этом. Я пишу телеграмбот. Но при запуске бота текст не выходит полностью, только нижняя часть, хотя в консоли полностью выходит. Можете, пожалуйста, помочь в этом?

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='мой токен')
URL = 'https://retrofm.ru/index.ph...
HEADERS = {
'user_agent': 'блаблабла'
}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
horoscopes = soup.findAll('div', class_='horoscope_item floats_wrapper')
for i in horoscopes:
text = i.find('div', class_='text_box').text

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def main(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваш гороскоп на сегодня:' + text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

ТОЛЬКО ЭТО ВЫХОДИТ:

> ```
> Ваш гороскоп на сегодня:
> 25.04.2020.
> Рыбы
> Рыбам - следует прислушаться к советам старших – это поможет избежать серьёзных ошибок.
> ```

Нету предыдущих. Буду очень признательна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
horoscopes = soup.findAll('div', class_='horoscope_item floats_wrapper')
for i in horoscopes:
    text = i.find('div', class_='text_box').text
```

Копируется последний `i` элемент, потому что `text =`, всё время присваивает новое значение, а старое удаляет. Попробуйте сделать.

```
text += i.find('div', class_='text_box').text
```

Но перед этим, создайте пустую переменную `text = ''`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: «Спасибо» на нашем сайте выражается голосом «за» и принятием ответа (галочка и треугольник вверх у ответа).